# QGIS PCT to RGB Attribute Error

Tags: qgis, rgb, attributeerror

I want to run this script, but it always gives me this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\bin\pct2rgb.py", line 121, in  ct_size =
> ct.GetCount()  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'GetCount'

I tried it with different images - all the same problem...

Can anybody explain what tcp means?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:

Save as and then tick on "rendered image"